# Display the error message returned form Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, error-handling

I need to get the whole error message returned from MySQL and assign it to `@error_string` :

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION   
       BEGIN 
        SET @error_string = 'SQLEXCEPTION_ERROR_MESSAGE'; <-- here
       END;
```

Is there any alternative, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/get-diagnostics.html):

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
      GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
        code = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, error_string = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    END;
```

I am just not sure about the use of local vs. user variables. User ones are visible for entire session and written in the `@var` form and if you need them, try to just adding @ to the var names in that statement.

Comment: Is that working also for MySQL v5.1.73 ?

Comment: @YassineLAADIDI seems to be only 5.6+ unfortunately and I did not find a way to emulate it.